# Can't Compile Working Xamarin.iOS Build only on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have been wrestling with the build settings on Visual Studio for Mac to create a working build on iTunes Connect that doesn't crash sections of the app after I install it through Test Flight. Here's the different behavior I'm experiencing depending on the Build settings/configuration and if I'm deploying to real device or iOS Simulator:

[image: iOS Sim build settings page] 
- With these settings the app works perfectly fine in RELEASE mode with the iOS Simulator.

Now for the settings for an real iPhone as the platform:
[image: iPhone device build settings]
- I used the exact same build settings as "Release/iPhoneSimulator"(the exception being, "Supported Architectures" since the only choice for iPhone is `ARM64` and the only choice for iOS Simulator is `x86_64`)

- The app will load fine but about half of the NavController sections I open up from the home page will crash the app. Again, the app works fine on the iOS simulator with the same release build settings.
- If I check the "Enable device-specific builds" then redeploy to my phone, then it all works again! Yet there is a warning not to use this setting in release mode. Again, only checking (enabling) this box, will prevent my app from crashing in release mode on a physical iPhone.
  [image: enable device specific builds checkbox]

-If I do enable device-specific build and create an bundle with those working build settings, upload to iTunes Connect and install the app on my phone through Test Flight then the same crashes will happen again.

How do you debug behavior like this in release mode? I know the app can work fine but why do I need "Enable device-specific build" turned on to make it work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I "doubt" that you are seeing "weird complier behavior". The iOS simulator vs. physical device operation is different in feature/functions and should not be used the "only" item in a test matrix of iOS version|feature|function for an app. What is the actual symbolized crash that you are getting?

Comment: You have something that breaks and it is not on those screens, so search somewhere else and you'll probably won't have to ask when you find it. Just like this question is not reproducible, not for this site.

Comment: Thank you @SushiHangover. I edited my post to remove the words "weird complier". It now states, "How do you debug behavior like this in release mode?" How do I view a symbolized crash?

Comment: @ToddMatthews https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, could you please check Link Behavior? It seems to me that the problem here.
   Set don't link and check result. If everything is fine. Than you need to read following article: [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows)
2. Secondly, how debug in release mode. You can use AppCenter(HockeyApp) crash analytics(for me works well).

Comment: Using AppCenter for release mode crash report is extremely helpful. Thank you Yauhen.